# How do I access SQL Server from Windows 8 apps?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, windows-8

I realize that a local SQL Server instance is not accessible to my Windows 8 app. Instead, I have a SQL Server in Azure. In SQL Server Management Studio, I just change the querystring and interact with the Azure database like any other. How can I reference that database in my Windows 8 app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access directly on sql databases.. Because Windows 8 Apps different from windows forms.
But you can be used web services or azure, amazon services, storage files etc.

Comment: What is this "amazon"? Just kidding. ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is what the [Azure Mobile Services SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) is for.   [Scott Guthrie did a writeup on it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/08/28/announcing-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx) a while back.

Undoubtedly you're aware that both ado.net and Entity Framework are missing from WinRT...  Notice the [glaring absence of support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for System.Data.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you want to develop a web service talking to your database, deploy it to IIS on your Azure instance and then consume it from your Windows 8 application (by adding a web reference to your web service in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2):

You can also place an OData head on the database, then use various OData client-side libraries to talk to it via REST. See http://www.odata.org/libraries for both client and server libraries. SQL Server on Azure is definitely supported, as is .NET, JavaScript, and other platforms on the client side.