# Connect SQL Server database in Windows 8 App?

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2012

I'm working on Windows 8 Desktop Application and I'm using a SQL Server database. But I cannot figure out how to connect to that SQL Server database with this.

Comment: You should show us what your tried until now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access SQL Server from Windows 8 apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770834/how-do-i-access-sql-server-from-windows-8-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try SQLite , I used it and it worked fine for me . Here's a tutorial and the official website

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

http://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET look up the SqlConnection class

Comment: The Metro Windows store app profile excludes the entire System.Data.* namespace. You won't be able to refer to SqlConnection class directly in your store app project.